# GroupText Changed when we open particular Group in expandable list view of android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a problem that My grouptext get automatically changed when we click on particular group to open. I unable to find the source of this problem. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

[image]

after Open:

[image]

**Code(Expandable Adapter):**

```
public class ExpResearchListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    // Sample data set. children[i] contains the children (String[]) for
    // groups[i].
    Context context;
    private String[] groups = { "Research by Brand", "Research by Category",
        "Research by Price" , "Research by Fuel Economy", "Recently Viewed"};
    GridView label;
    TextView groupText;
    String group;
    ImageView groupImg;
    //ArrayList<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> groupImage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> childElement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Integer[][] children = { 
            { R.drawable.icon_1, R.drawable.icon_2, R.drawable.icon_3, R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_5, R.drawable.icon_6, R.drawable.icon_7, R.drawable.icon_8, R.drawable.icon_9,
                R.drawable.icon_10, R.drawable.icon_11, R.drawable.icon_12, R.drawable.icon_13, R.drawable.icon_14, R.drawable.icon_15, R.drawable.icon_16, R.drawable.icon_17, R.drawable.icon_18,
                R.drawable.icon_19, R.drawable.icon_20, R.drawable.icon_21, R.drawable.icon_22, R.drawable.icon_23, R.drawable.icon_24, R.drawable.icon_25, R.drawable.icon_26, R.drawable.icon_27,
                R.drawable.icon_28, R.drawable.icon_29, R.drawable.icon_30, R.drawable.icon_31, R.drawable.icon_32, R.drawable.icon_33, R.drawable.icon_34, R.drawable.icon_35, R.drawable.icon_36,
                R.drawable.icon_37, R.drawable.icon_38, R.drawable.icon_39, R.drawable.icon_40, R.drawable.icon_41, R.drawable.icon_42, R.drawable.icon_43, R.drawable.icon_44, R.drawable.icon_45,
                R.drawable.icon_46} 
            };
    LinearLayout linear;

    public ExpResearchListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<Integer> groupImage, ArrayList<Integer> childElement, LinearLayout linear)
    {
        this.context=context;
        //this.groups = groups;
        this.groupImage = groupImage;
        this.childElement = childElement;
        this.linear = linear;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int i = 0;
        try {
        i = children[groupPosition].length;

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return 1;
    }



    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_research_grid, null);
            label = (GridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gv_ResearchList_Child);
            label.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(context, childElement));
            label.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);

            // initialize the following variables (i've done it based on your layout
            // note: rowHeightDp is based on my grid_cell.xml, that is the height i've
            //    assigned to the items in the grid.
            //final int spacingDp = 20;
            final int colWidthDp = 50;
            final int rowHeightDp = (childElement.size()/3)*10;
            //final int rowHeightDp = 107;

            // convert the dp values to pixels
            //final float COL_WIDTH = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * colWidthDp;
            final float COL_WIDTH = 10;
            //final float ROW_HEIGHT = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * rowHeightDp;
            final float ROW_HEIGHT = 107f;
            final float SPACING = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 0;
            System.out.println("===================================RowHeight"+ROW_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println("===================================RowHeightDP"+rowHeightDp);


            // calculate the column and row counts based on your display
            final int colCount = (int)Math.floor((linear.getWidth() - (2 * SPACING)) / (COL_WIDTH + SPACING));
            final int rowCount = (int)Math.ceil((childElement.size() + 0d) / 3);
            //final int rowCount = 16;

            // calculate the height for the current grid
            final int GRID_HEIGHT = Math.round(rowCount * (ROW_HEIGHT + SPACING));
            System.out.println("===================================GHieght"+GRID_HEIGHT);
            System.out.println("===================================colCount"+colCount);
            System.out.println("===================================rowCount"+rowCount);
            // set the height of the current grid
            label.getLayoutParams().height = GRID_HEIGHT;
        }





        return convertView;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        //return groups.get(groupPosition);
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.research_list_exp_group, null);
            groupText = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_ResearchList_ExpParentElement);
            groupImg = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_ResearchList_GroupParentImage);
            group = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            // convertView.setClickable(false);
            groupText.setText(groups[groupPosition]);
            groupImg.setImageResource(groupImage.get(groupPosition));
        }


        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the gridadapter class coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused in `getGroupView()` function, you are using `convertView` wrongly. If `convertView` is null, you are correctly inflating a layout and filling the views. 
However if it is not null you are not changing the view! The view is a recycled view - it's one of the former group item views, but you don't know which one! You have to fill it too.
When you click on the group item, the content is redrawn and all the views might be recycled.

You have the same problem in `getChildView()` function.

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial, especially example 9.5. It shows how to use recycle view properly (and also how to use the holder pattern).

Note that there's another problem in your code - you are trying to use `GridView` inside `ListView` (`ExpandableListView`). Don't do that! Dont' use two widgets capable of scrolling one inside the other. Don't do such thing unless each of the scrolling views uses different axis for scrolling.

Comment: there is no example 3.4